# Laravel BoilerPlate : Defining Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have used [Laravel Boilerplate](http://laravel-boilerplate.com/) for development of my application. Beside that I have installed [L5Modular](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular) with it. So i define the route Like following inside my Modules

```
<?php

Route::group(array('module' => 'test', 'middleware' => ['web','auth'], 'prefix'=>'frontend','namespace' => 'App\Modules\test\Controllers'), function() {

    Route::resource('test', 'TestController');

});
```

But when i tried to access the route **http://localhost/blog/public/test/create** it's showing 404 Error.

Why my route not accessed? is there any error of defining route?

Comment: Laravel doesn't support being installed in a subdirectory out of the box, you'll need to customise the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Could u please try  http://localhost/blog/public/index.php/test/create

Comment: you also needed to show the content of `TestController`

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure a virtual host to get laravel working, that's quite easy and even easier if you're using any software such as MAMP or XAMPP.

If you're on a MAC I'd suggest to have a look at [laravel valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet): you'll have your web server running in seconds.

If you don't want to do any of this, you'll have to change a few things in order to get Laravel working in a sub directory.

Answer (score -1):

You might forget to write `frontend` prefix to URL. Try to access by:

http://localhost/blog/public/frontend/test/create

Comment: Laravel doesn't work in sub directories (out of the box). Look at my answer or read @apokryfos comment.

Comment: Did you write `frontend` prifix to your url?

Comment: I mean did you try by : http://localhost/blog/public/frontend/test/create

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135840/discussion-between-mrabbani-and-user57).

Comment: You have such a toxic behaviour @mrabbani.